# Django and localhost and sessions

Tags: django, session, localhost

This is a rather old question, that's been asked over and over again, and I'm even going to reference a django ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10560  that explains the issue.

But the ticket is 3 years, and I was wondering if anyone has found a workaround.

Basically, we deploy a product to clients, who have no tech skills, and they want to access our app via localhost.  Is there anyway, we can make sessions work and be able to persist logins, and other session data?

I've read that it's a security issue with browsers, but I thought someone might have good insight into a workaround??

Comment: Is there an issue with accessing 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0?  Could you describe more about what your are trying to do with your clients?  I'm unclear about "access our app via localhost"

Comment: @TimEdgar I was given this question by my manager, I'll check on that and report back shortly